# Must $n$ independent Wiener processes be simultaneously positive at some time?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Consider $n$ independent one-dimensional Wiener processes $(W_i)_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}$.

> Is there with probability $1$ some time $t\in[0,1]$ such that $W_i(t)>0$ for every $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$?

For $n=1$ this is obvious, but I don't see how to show this for $n\geqslant2$.

Comment: Excellent question. I took the liberty to reformulate it, slightly.

Comment: Did you try to use the fact that P[W_i(t)>0 for every i, for some t<1]=P[W_i(t)>0 for every i, for some >1] and that P[W_i(t)>0 for every i, for some 4^n<t<4.4^n] does not depend on n?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't follow. I am not that familiar with these processes. Why is this true? Can you give me some reference?

Comment: First, invariance by the inversion (W(t)) -> (tW(1/t)). Second, invariance by scaling (W(t)) -> (2^nW(t/4^n)).

Comment: Ok, I get the first now. But for the second, if I apply the scale invariance P[W_i(t)>0 for all i, for some 4^n<t<4.4^n] = P[W_i(t)>0 for all i, for some 1<t<4] and I don't see why should this be independent of n.

Comment: Because the RHS you just wrote in your last comment does not depend on n, that's why.

Comment: @Did Oh yes, I thought $n$ is the sample size, pardon me for being dumb. Where I got now is  $P[\exists t<1 \, \forall i=1,..,n \, W_i(t)>0] = P[\exists t>1 \,\forall i=1,..,n \,W_i(t)>0] = P[\bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty} \exists t\in[2^k,2^{k+1})\, \forall i=1,..,n \,W_i(t)>0] \geq P[\bigcup_{k=0}^{m} \exists t\in[2^k,2^{k+1}) \,\forall i=1,..,n \,W_i(t)>0]$  for all $m$, but to conclude as $m\to\infty$ I need to have something like independence of $[\exists t\in[a,b) \,W(t)>0]$ and $[\exists t\in[c,d)\, W(t)>0]$ for $a<b<c<d$. And I don't have that.

Comment: "And I don't have that." Which is why I suggested to look at this approach, not that it was a full proof.

Comment: Fine, thanks. I just needed to make the whole thing clear for me. I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there with probability $1$ some time $t\in[0,1]$ such that $W_i(t)>0$ for every $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$?

Yes, for every $n$. Here is a proof.

The distribution of each $W_i$ is invariant by the transformation $t\mapsto tW_i(1/t)$, hence the probability to be computed is also the probability that there exists some $t\gt1$ such that $W_i(t)\gt0$ simultaneously for every ${1\leqslant i\leqslant n}$.
We now define iteratively an increasing sequence of random times as follows.

First, note that, for any Brownian motion $W$, $P(W(t)\gt0\mid W(0)=-1)\to\frac12$ when $t\to\infty$ hence there exists some deterministic and finite $\theta$ such that $P(W(\theta)\gt0\mid W(0)=-1)\geqslant\frac13$. Then, by scaling,  for every $x$,
$$
P(W(x^2\theta)\gt0\mid W(0)=x)\geqslant\tfrac13.
$$
Let $T_0=1$. For every $k\geqslant0$, knowing $T_k$, let 
$$
T_{k+1}=T_k+\theta\cdot\max\limits_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}W_i(T_k)^2.
$$
Then, almost surely, for every ${1\leqslant i\leqslant n}$,
$$
P(W_i(T_{k+1})\gt0\mid \mathcal F^{W_i}_{T_k})\geqslant\tfrac13.
$$ 
Since the Brownian motions $W_i$ are independent, this implies that $P[A_{k+1}\mid\mathcal G_k]\geqslant3^{-n}$, where
$$
A_k=[\forall 1\leqslant i\leqslant n,\,W_i(T_{k})\gt0],\qquad\mathcal G_k=\sigma(A_\ell;\,\ell\leqslant k).
$$
In particular, $P[A_{k+1}^c\mid A_1^c\cap\cdots\cap A_k^c]\leqslant1-3^{-n}$ hence the probability that no event $A_\ell$ with $\ell\leqslant k$ holds is at most $(1-3^{-n})^k$, which goes to zero when $k\to\infty$. 
Conversely, the event $A_k$ holds for at least some $k$, almost surely, in particular, almost surely there exists some $t$ such that $W_i(t)\gt0$ simultaneously for every ${1\leqslant i\leqslant n}$. QED.

The same approach shows that, for every level $h$, almost surely there exists some $t$ such that $W_i(t)\gt h$ simultaneously for every ${1\leqslant i\leqslant n}$.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!

Comment: Thanks. What is the context of this question?

Comment: Hi Did, Won't this work? : W.p.1 there is an unbounded increasing sequence $\left\{a_i\right\}$ such that $W_1\left(a_i\right)$ is positive for all $i$. We just need to prove that w.p.1 there exists a subsequence on which $W_2$ is also positive. This seems to be true because if take a subsequence sparse enough, then the values of $W_2$ are 'almost' independent (The probablity that a multivariate Gaussian vector is negative is a continuous function of the covariance matrix)

Comment: @bleh [seems to be true + sparse enough + 'almost' independent] $\ne$ [proof]. To turn these ideas into a proof would probably lead you to something similar to the proof in my post.

Comment: Hi, This is what I had in mind. We prove that for fixed naturals $N$ and $m$, the probability that $W_2$ is negative for all $a_n$ when $n>N$ is less than $1/2^m$. The probability that m+1 - dimensional zero mean Gaussian vector is negative only (continously)depends on the pairwise correlations. This is $1/2^{m+1}$, when they are all zero. Notice that we can choose $m+1$ instants among the given sequence (by virtue of it's unboundedness), on which pairwise correlations of the value of $W_2$ is as close to zero as we want.